# How to specify argument value from Bash/ZSH alias?

Tags: bash, zsh, alias

In my .zshrc I have the following aliases

```
alias ls="colorls"
alias l="colorls -1"
alias la="colorls -a"
alias ld="colorls -d"
alias lf="colorls -f"
alias lt="colorls --tree"
alias ltd="colorls --tree=$1"`
```

I have used the ltd alias to run colorls with the tree argument which requires an integer for tree depth.

I was hoping that by running ltd 5 (or any specified number) I would be aliasing `colorls --tree=5`, but this appears to be incompatible.

Additionally colorls requires the integer to be specified directly after the equals sign without a space. This means that `alias ltd="colorls --tree="` doesn't work either.

How can I perform this method of aliasing properly? Thank you

Comment: If you're using zsh, why is this tagged bash too?

Comment: Neither bash- nor zsh-aliases expect positional parameters. $1 does not make sense. Further, please restrict your question to a single programming language (bash or zsh), in particular since I don't see a bash question here.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use a shell function instead of that monstrosity of an entire shell script:

```bash
ltd() {
  if [[ $# -eq 0 ]]; then
    print -u 2 "ltd needs a depth argument"
    return 1
  fi
  local depth=$1
  shift
  lscolor --tree=$depth "$@"
}
```

then `ltd 5 blah blah blah` will use the first argument as the argument to that `--tree` option, and pass the rest through unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer during my time putting this question together. The answer comes from [here](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/035)

with the code

```
#!/bin/sh
# POSIX

die() {
    printf '%s\n' "$1" >&2
    exit 1
}

# Initialize all the option variables.
# This ensures we are not contaminated by variables from the environment.
file=
verbose=0

while :; do
    case $1 in
        -h|-\?|--help)
            show_help    # Display a usage synopsis.
            exit
            ;;
        -f|--file)       # Takes an option argument; ensure it has been specified.
            if [ "$2" ]; then
                file=$2
                shift
            else
                die 'ERROR: "--file" requires a non-empty option argument.'
            fi
            ;;
        --file=?*)
            file=${1#*=} # Delete everything up to "=" and assign the remainder.
            ;;
        --file=)         # Handle the case of an empty --file=
            die 'ERROR: "--file" requires a non-empty option argument.'
            ;;
        -v|--verbose)
            verbose=$((verbose + 1))  # Each -v adds 1 to verbosity.
            ;;
        --)              # End of all options.
            shift
            break
            ;;
        -?*)
            printf 'WARN: Unknown option (ignored): %s\n' "$1" >&2
            ;;
        *)               # Default case: No more options, so break out of the loop.
            break
    esac

    shift
done

# if --file was provided, open it for writing, else duplicate stdout
if [ "$file" ]; then
    exec 3> "$file"
else
    exec 3>&1
fi

colorls --tree=$1
```

and the alias in .zshrc

```
alias ltd="zsh ~/ltd.sh"
```